# How do I put the timestamp in the "check in" or "check out" column based on the user's response in the Google form?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-forms, google-sheets-timestamp

I created a Google form that allows users to clock in/out. The form asks two questions: their pin number and whether they want to check in or out. When the user clicks on "check in" and submits, the form or the spreadsheet should input the timestamp in the "check in" column and so on for "check out" option.

How would I do this through Google script?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the copyDown add-on by filling in the right formula in line 2.
You can find the copyDown add-on here:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copydown/lipbbdpmkcbplmfnbholpabinnnkbbda